# Jquery / javascript show next image, hide previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html on a page and want to hide the first image and show the next when I click an image link, e.g #next or #previous.

This is the html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
            <input type="image" style="border-width:0px;" src="previous.gif" id="previous">
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="image1.jpg" class="image_in_collection">
            <img src="image2.jpg" class="image_in_collection">
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td valign="middle">
            <input type="image" style="border-width:0px;" src="next.gif" id="next">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZU85R/2/

Comment: This is probably best accomplished by a jQuery plugin, since I assume your are making some kind of image gallery. Look at jQuery Cycle. It can make the buttons and provide nice transitions for you. Pretty easy to use as well, and highly customisable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZU85R/2/ Would have thought some simple JS would do it, am I missing something, this is my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next() selector with the is(':visible') selector to achieve this.
http://api.jquery.com/next/